# Можно ли скопировать функцию в другую функцию, и если нет, то какие есть альтернативы?

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс:

```cpp
#include "list.h"

class Renderer{
    public:
        list<int> pressedButtons;
        list<int> pressedKeys;

        void (*updFunc)(list<int>, list<int>);

        Renderer();

        void setUpdateFunc(void (*f)(list<int>, list<int>)){
            updFunc=f;
        }

        void run(){
            while(1){
                //Event polling
                //window clear
                updFunc(pressedKeys, pressedButtons);
                //window update
            }       
        }
};
```

По моей задумке, сначала создаётся пустая заготовка под функцию (`updFunc`) и в функции `setUpdateFunc` задаётся уже точное значение функции `updFunc`. При попытке это сделать выскакивает ошибка: `Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением`, я так понял что функция - это константа. Вопрос, как можно сделать что-то подобное?

[list.cpp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11qaoqMCNocqU7mhuHx9D0Qru9G4f0E21/view?usp=share_link) [list.h](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fNTx_4BGpm5gxXB9zt5GjDQBJ73nF-tu/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Для начала — `void (*updFunc)(list<Keyboard::Key>, list<Mouse::Button>);`. Но это для свободных функций; для функций-членов класса синтаксис несколько сложнее. Понять, что именно планируется использовать у вас, из приведенных отрывков сложновато...

Comment: @Harry Это всё члены класса

Comment: Ну сделайте нормальный [минимальный компилируемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), чтоб свой не придумывать :)

Comment: @Harry, сделал.

Comment: Обратите внимание на слово *компилируемый*. У меня SFML не установлен.

Comment: @Harry А так нормально?

Comment: @Harry правда ошибка в таком случае, исчезает, и смысл в вопросе отстуствует

Comment: @Igen отлично, значит вы нашли в какой момент ошибка исчезает. Вот вы попытались избавиться от SFML, и ошибка исчезла. Но при этом вы не избавлялись от класса, и класс у вас работает. Значит, класс тут вообще ни при чём, а проблема была в том как вы используете SFML... Попробуйте вернуть всё как было и избавиться от класса.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я не знаю, как так получилось но ошибка и с sfml, исчезла, даже не знаю что способствовало решению. Как можно закрыть вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на этот код, может, станет понятнее?

```
void f1(int i) { cout << "f1(" << i << ")\n"; }
void f2(int i) { cout << "f2(" << i << ")\n"; }

struct Test
{
    void (*free_fun)(int);
    void (Test::*mem)(int);

    void m1(int i){ cout << "m1(" << i << ")\n"; }
    void m2(int i){ cout << "m2(" << i << ")\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Test t;
    t.free_fun = f1;
    t.free_fun(1);
    t.free_fun = f2;
    t.free_fun(2);

    t.mem = &Test::m1;
    (t.*t.mem)(3);
    t.mem = &Test::m2;
    (t.*t.mem)(4);
}
```